# Enable Java Socks4 Support

Tags: java, proxy, socks, java-12

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/90020/java-socks4-client) it's pretty much what I want but I don't know how to use reflect never used it. Just asking how I would make this work.

If someone can help direct me to the right solution is the best.
Thnx for your help.

Comment: I think it would be better to explain what you are trying to do. Are you using the Socket(Proxy) constructor and trying to force the V4 instead of V5 protocol?

Comment: socks4 is disabled by default
```private boolean useV4 = false;```
and i need to use socks4 proxy to connect to something in java.

Comment: Not clear why you can't set the socksProxyVersion property to 4. Can you update the question with the SOCKS configuration that you have configured as I think that would be a good start.